# How to compare variables in more than two datasets in sas?

Tags: sas

How to compare variables in more than two tables?
I even tried with compare but its not comparing more than two tables.

Comment: How many variables  you want to compare?

Comment: You can't use Proc compare. You'll need to develop custom code to achieve your results.

Comment: Yes compare won't work, you can merge the datasets together and then can use something like , if A1=A2 then flag=1 else 0.

Answer (score 0):

Using PROC COMPARE will not tell you much about the data aside from whether or not 2 tables have the same variable (which I assume is not the info you need).

You'll need to merge the tables together using MERGE.  Your code will look something like this:

```
DATA TABLE1 TABLE2;
MERGE TABLE1 (IN=A) TABLE2 (IN=B);
BY VAR1;
IF A AND B THEN OUTPUT NEWTABLENAME;
ELSE IF A AND NOT B THEN OUTPUT NEWTABLENAME2;
RUN;
```

The BY statement tells SAS which variable you'd like the tables to merge on, as SAS isn't going to just smush some extra columns onto your existing table.

[You can check out more about what PROC COMPARE does here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#compare-overview.htm)

[You can read more about PROC MERGE here](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/58133/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001318494.htm)